# BLE is not detecting in Chrome browser

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-authenticator, webauthn, fido

I am trying to connect my Android application with web via Bluetooth. But Chrome browser is not detecting my Bluetooth enabled smartphone. I am using Google-FIDO2-Android API.

I am working on Chrome Browser 74.0.3729.157 (64-bit), Nexus Phone, MacBook Pro (Mojave-10.14.5).

How can I proceed on this?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do. If authenticating please describe use case in detail. Also list OS versions of all related devices (i.e. which Nexus Phone running what version of Android).

Comment: This sounds like it is not a programming problem. If that is so, please post it to _Super User_ instead, together with some information about your environment (e.g. MacBook logs).

Comment: I don;t think that Chrome browser has something to do with Bluetooth. What exactly you want to do with chrome and your device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open Chrome
2. Go to `chrome://flags/`
3. search by **Web Authentication API BLE support**
4. Change to **Enabled**

This helps you to enable bluetooth communication for Webauthn. They said this flag will be enabled by default in the future. Let's see.

If it doesn't work, it should be your authenticator problem. And you should figure out where is the error and post here to get help.

Comment: Seems like chrome removed this API BLE support recently. is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently the flag is named as `Web Authentication caBLE v2 support` #enable-web-authentication-cable-v2-support.

Enable this flag to use Web BLE support for FIDO2.